# Can verification code emails be redirected or forwarded to another email address?

Tags: error, oauth

We have multiple users that login to the same Salesforce1 App company wide. When at a new site with a new WAN IP, the verification code prompt generates. Can that code be emailed to a different address than the one associated with the Salesforce login?

Comment: Given SF wouldn't be overly pleased with the 'multiple users via single login' approach, I seriously doubt you'll find a way around this one sorry.